# Extract entire string following specific characters & trouble with str_extract()

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract every character following a specific string. I can get this to work on regular expression testers such as Pythex (if there's a good regex expression tester for R, let me know).

I'm trying to get every character after "100" in the following string:

```
\nDec\n\n\n\n\n\n\n8238\n\n\n\n \n                                    \n\n1st \n\n\n100\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n10.40\n (1.5) \n\n\n\n1st\n\n\nLJ\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n7.47m\n (1.4) \n \n\n24' 6.25\"\n\n\n\n\n3rd\n\n\nSP\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n14.41m\n \n \n\n47' 3.5\"\n\n\n\n\n2nd\n\n\nHJ\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n1.85m\n \n \n\n6' 0.75\"\n\n\n\n\n9th\n\n\n400\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n46.78\n \n\n\n\n1st\n\n\n110H\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n13.98\n (1.9) \n\n\n\n1st\n\n\nDT\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n39.91m\n \n \n\n130' 11\"\n\n\n\n\n8th\n\n\nPV\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n4.70m\n \n \n\n15' 5\"\n\n\n\n\n4th\n\n\nJT\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n55.71m\n \n \n\n182' 9\"\n\n\n\n\n5th\n\n\n1500\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n4:23.57\n \n\n\n\n1st\n\n
```

On sites such as Pythex, I'm able to capture everything that comes after 100 ([see example](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3C%3D100).*&test_string=%5Cn%5Cn%5CtBig%20Ten%20Outdoor%20Track%20%26%20Field%20Championships%5Cn%5Cn%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20May%2014-16%2C%202021%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%5Cn%20%20%5CnDec%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn8238%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cn%5Cn1st%20%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn100%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn10.40%5Cn%20(1.5)%20%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn1st%5Cn%5Cn%5CnLJ%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn7.47m%5Cn%20(1.4)%20%5Cn%20%5Cn%5Cn24%27%206.25%5C%22%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn3rd%5Cn%5Cn%5CnSP%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn14.41m%5Cn%20%5Cn%20%5Cn%5Cn47%27%203.5%5C%22%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn2nd%5Cn%5Cn%5CnHJ%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn1.85m%5Cn%20%5Cn%20%5Cn%5Cn6%27%200.75%5C%22%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn9th%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn400%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn46.78%5Cn%20%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn1st%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn110H%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn13.98%5Cn%20(1.9)%20%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn1st%5Cn%5Cn%5CnDT%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn39.91m%5Cn%20%5Cn%20%5Cn%5Cn130%27%2011%5C%22%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn8th%5Cn%5Cn%5CnPV%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn4.70m%5Cn%20%5Cn%20%5Cn%5Cn15%27%205%5C%22%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn4th%5Cn%5Cn%5CnJT%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn55.71m%5Cn%20%5Cn%20%5Cn%5Cn182%27%209%5C%22%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn5th%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn1500%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn4%3A23.57%5Cn%20%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn1st%5Cn%5Cn&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)). However, when I try using stringr's str_extract, I only receive `""` as an output

```
dec_res <- "\nDec\n\n\n\n\n\n\n8238\n\n\n\n \n                                    \n\n1st \n\n\n100\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n10.40\n (1.5) \n\n\n\n1st\n\n\nLJ\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n7.47m\n (1.4) \n \n\n24' 6.25\"\n\n\n\n\n3rd\n\n\nSP\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n14.41m\n \n \n\n47' 3.5\"\n\n\n\n\n2nd\n\n\nHJ\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n1.85m\n \n \n\n6' 0.75\"\n\n\n\n\n9th\n\n\n400\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n46.78\n \n\n\n\n1st\n\n\n110H\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n13.98\n (1.9) \n\n\n\n1st\n\n\nDT\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n39.91m\n \n \n\n130' 11\"\n\n\n\n\n8th\n\n\nPV\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n4.70m\n \n \n\n15' 5\"\n\n\n\n\n4th\n\n\nJT\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n55.71m\n \n \n\n182' 9\"\n\n\n\n\n5th\n\n\n1500\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n4:23.57\n \n\n\n\n1st\n\n"

> str_extract(dec_res, "(?<=100).*")
[1] ""
```

Is my issue that I don't know R-specific regex syntax? Or, is this a particular behavior of str_extract?

Comment: No, it is because `.` does not match line break chars by default. Use `str_extract(dec_res, "(?s)(?<=100).*")` where the inline modifier `(?s)` will make `.` match line break chars, too. Note that this is true here since you are using `stringr` regex method that uses the ICU regex engine. Basic TRE engine does not require this modifier as `.` matches any char in the default base R regex methods (without `perl=TRUE`).

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if I was missing something so that the `.` character also matched line break characters. I looked for that in the arguments of str_extract() but when I didn't find anything I got stuck.